# ATMEGA 12 MHz bord initializing USART 0

Tags: atmega

I initialize my China ATMEGA 2560 12MHz board according to the ATMEL datasheet.

TXenable = 1, RXenable = 1,  8 bits, 1 stopbit(s), NO parity. Baud rate is supposed to be 9600 baud.

According to the ATMEL datasheet formula this is 77 (10) . Burn the ATMEGA using Atmel Studio 6 on my XP pro (Sp. 4).

But when I transmit data (9600, N, 8, 1)  I get nothing but rubbish on the screen.  When I press a key on the keyboard I still get rubbish on the screen as an echo .

It is obvious the the baudrate is wrong, so I had to modify the baud-rate to a slower one, to make i work.

But I wonder: What is wrong here ??
I do follow the instructions on the Atmel datasheet (programming the usart 0) byte by byte, but still get wrong results.

Can anyone give me a hint why ?  (Is the China chip so different from the original one .. or .. )

Thanks

Kris

Comment: What is the condition of `CKDIV8` fuse?

Comment: I'll check and come back (late evening now) .

Comment: The fuse named CKDIV8 is unmarked.  (Open).    Only marked fuse is SPIEN . Fuses BODLEVEL, BOOTSZ and SUT_CKSEL contains text (in a selectbox) all other fuses are unmarked except SPIEN (as before mentioned).

Comment: And how is the clock source setup? I recommend generate a rectangular signal on some port and measure its period. If the timing is correct, the transmission speed is setup incorrectly.

Comment: @Peter Resnick   The baudrate speed is wrong. Definitely. I have tried to justify it, by writing some code, that changes (+/-) the baurate, but it appears that these changes has no effect at all.  And btw. the baudrate is calculated from the formula in the datasheet.  I have to do some experimenting, as I don't have a working o-scope at hand.  I will make a routine, that transmit a known pattern wirh baudrate changes (eventually by calling address 0x0000  / (resetting)  ) and make that work , before I start trying reading back. Anyway thanks for your help.   Kris

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tests and (re-) programming I found that the China ATMEGA 2560 12Mhz board USART_0 functions fine with the a baud-rate value of 0x0068.

Comment: Out of interest, how are you communicating with the board?  Putty, Realterm?  You will get garbage if the BAUD on the Client Side does not match that on the ATMEL.

Comment: @MIKE  Thanks for the comment., but before I wrote the comment above I did tested it. I tried 2 different terminal-types. Both worked "like a dream" at 9600,n.8.1  Full ASCII range an some the norwegian national characters (æøå).